# Cant figure out why the program doesn't work when it gets to a section in my script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am working on a small script to make a large amount of folders, it gets to the calculate section (Yes, i know its inefficient but i can't get the FOR loop to work), but it doesn't do anything after that. I have no idea why it does it, it doesn't really give me enough information. I do know that it is making it to the Calculation section, it just ends the program after that though. Maybe i can fix the FOR loop if  solve it?

```
    @echo off
    :Var
    cls
    set created=0


    :select
    Echo How many folders will there be?(1-100)
    set /p Count=
    if %Count% LSS 1 GOTO Var
    if %Count% GTR 100 GOTO Var
    :2sel
    cls
    Echo There will be %Count% folders!
    Echo.
    Echo How many layers deep will this go?(1-10)
    set /p Layers=
     if %Layers% LSS 1 GOTO 2sel
     if %Layers% GTR 10 GOTO 2sel
    cls
    Echo There will be %Layers% Layers and %Count% Folders.
    Echo.
    Echo Are you sure? 1)Yes  2)No
    set /p choi=
    if %choi% EQU 1 GOTO Calculate
    GOTO Var

    :Calculate
    pause
    cls
    if %Layers% EQU 1(
    set dis= %Count%
    GOTO say
    )
    if %Layers% EQU 2(
    set dis= %Count% * %Count%
    GOTO say
    )
    if %Layers% EQU 3(
    set dis= %Count% * %Count% * %Count%
    GOTO say
    )
    if %Layers% EQU 4(
    set dis= %Count% * %Count% * %Count% * %Count%
    GOTO say
    )
    if %Layers% EQU 5(
    set dis= %Count% * %Count% * %Count% * %Count% * %Count%
    GOTO say
    )
    if %Layers% EQU 6(
    set dis= %Count% * %Count% * %Count% * %Count% * %Count% * %Count%
    GOTO say
    )
    if %Layers% EQU 7(
    set dis= %Count% * %Count% * %Count% * %Count% * %Count% * %Count% * %Count%
    GOTO say
    )
    if %Layers% EQU 8(
    set dis= %Count% * %Count% * %Count% * %Count% * %Count% * %Count% * %Count% * %Count%
    GOTO say
    )
    if %Layers% EQU 9(
    set dis= %Count% * %Count% * %Count% * %Count% * %Count% * %Count% * %Count% * %Count% * %Count%
    GOTO say
    )
    if %Layers% EQU 10(
    set dis= %Count%*%Count%*%Count%*%Count%*%Count%*%Count%*%Count%*%Count%*%Count%*%Count%
    GOTO say
    )
    :say
    Echo You are about to make %dis% files.
    Echo Are you sure? 1)Yes  2)No
    pause>NUL
    set /p choi2=
    if %choi% EQU 2 GOTO Var
    )
    cls
    Echo %made% / %dis%
    pause
    :one

    :two
    :three
    :four
    :five
    :six
    :seven
    :eight
    :nine
    :ten
```

Comment: There needs to be a space character immediately preceding all of your opening perentheses, _except for those in your `Echo` statements_. Additionally you should replace your `set /p` for the choice command, _which is considerably more robust_.

Comment: Also check out `set /?` and read about the `/a` switch.

Comment: `:Calculate`, `set dis=1`, `for /l %%a in (1,1,%layers%) do set /a dis*=count`, `goto say`

Comment: First two steps in troubleshooting a batch file.  Turn `ECHO ON` at the top of your script and run the batch file from the command prompt instead of executing it with your mouse.  That will show you where it is failing and what the error message is.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could review this line

> > Echo Are you sure? 1)Yes  2)No
> >
> > pause>NUL4
> >
> > set /p choi2=
> >
> > if **%choi%** EQU 2 GOTO Var

and put

> > if %choi**2**% EQU 2 GOTO Var

Just a guess. ;) have a nice programming day !

Comment: I'm pretty sure i changed that after the fact, but ill see if that is the problem.

Comment: The most obvious errors are undetected and its why we must request to colleagues, friends the second opinion on our problems, code etc... When we have clear and nice code, we can show it and it is the case of your code. May be its another problem ! Send me your feedback.